# Авторизация в битриксе по e-mail?

Tags: php, битрикс

На сайте предусмотрена авторизация с помощью модальных окон. Вход выполняется по e-mail и паролю. Подключил необходимые стандартные компоненты, настроил для них шаблоны. Но при заполнении полей модального окна и нажатии на "Войти" переходим на страницу авторизации по логину ../auth. Да, если ввести логин и пароль то авторизация работает. Подскажите пожалуйста как осуществлять вход непосредственно из модального окна по e-mail??? Авторизованый пользователь после корректного ввода данных должен войти сразу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собствено битрикс авторизует глубоко в ядре, чтобы не было мучительно больно в init.php при авторизации воспользуемся событиями:

```
AddEventHandler("main", "OnBeforeUserLogin", array("CCustomHookEvent", "DoBeforeUserLoginHandler"));
class CCustomHookEvent {
        //  Проверяем пришел ли email или login и если email авторизуем по нему
        function DoBeforeUserLoginHandler( &$arFields )
        {
            $userLogin = $_POST["USER_LOGIN"];
            if (isset($userLogin))
            {
                $isEmail = strpos($userLogin,"@");
                if ($isEmail>0)
                {
                    $arFilter = Array("EMAIL"=>$userLogin);
                    $rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="id"), ($order="desc"), $arFilter);
                    if($res = $rsUsers->Fetch())
                    {
                        if($res["EMAIL"]==$arFields["LOGIN"])
                            $arFields["LOGIN"] = $res["LOGIN"];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // End 
}
```

Конкретно то что на тостере написано я бы не делал. Это плохо. Хотите обратитесь по аякс к компоненту, хотите да создайте свой шаблон, хотите даже сами проверьте есть ли юзер и сделайте $USER->Authorize($id) но вдумывайтесь что делаете.

Comment: ну что же тогда попробую вам помочь :) подождите я видео запишу. И выложу здесь

Comment: спасибо за предложение:) меня осенило)

Comment: @binliz: Ух ты, видео! А вы не хотите попросить у компании 1С за ваши старания вознаграждение.  Прям с [Рыжикова](https://ru-ru.facebook.com/rsv.bitrix). А то распинаетесь тут за бесплатно :)